# How to use the value returned by formatNumber in a String comparison

Tags: string, jsp, format, jstl, equals

I got this line to format a number :

`<fmt:formatNumber type="number" pattern="###,#######" value="1234567890" var="test"/>`

Above line output `123 4567890` with my current locale (french).

If I use below code :

`<c:set var="ref" value="123 4567890"/>
${ref == test}`

**It return false, why?**

First, I thought that `test` was no a String hence I tried that :

`<c:set var="test2" value="${test}"/>`

But `${ref == test2}` still return false.

Comment: Why don't you compare the actual model value instead of the locale-specific formatted human representation?

Comment: @BalusC Yeah you're right. Of course, what I'm trying is a bit silly. Actually I don't really need it. I was just playing with `formatNumber` and `replace` methods and I stumbled upon that weird behaviour. I'm not looking for a better/different solution. I'm just trying to understand why this test fails, why it can't work. I'm probably missing something in the way data are stored/compared using jstl.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the French locale uses a non-breaking space character (the "&nbsp", hex 0xA0 (160 decimal)), but you were using a regular space (character 32)

This should print **true**:

```
<fmt:formatNumber type="number" pattern="###,#######" value="1234567890" var="test"/>
<% pageContext.setAttribute("nbsp", String.valueOf('\u00a0'));%>
<c:set var="ref" value="123${nbsp}4567890"/>
ref is ${ref} <br />
test is ${test} <br />
${ref == test}
```

Comment: Please read my question, it's mentionned that it prints "123 4567890"

Comment: Right. Given the circumstances, that's what I suspect may be an incorrect fact. Try a simple small JSP with only the lines that I posted to see if your problem still persists

Comment: Yes still have it, when you execute that code it prints true?

Comment: Ok, I guess I figured it out - looks like it's a nbsp, and not space

Comment: It may have been something like that but no it still print false. If I inspect the page source, ${test} really contains a regular space.

Comment: Yep, page source contains a regular space but I printed out (int)charAt(), and saw that the "space" was 160 in "test" and 32 in "ref". It gave me "true". You may want to do something similar to find what that space character actually is:  -- something like <% char c = ((String)pageContext.getAttribute("test")).charAt(3); out.println((int)c); %>

Comment: If I use `<c:set var="test2" value="${fn:replace(test, '&#160;', '|')}"/>` nothing is replaced so no I don't think it's a non breaking space (I have also tried with &#xa0; and &nbsp;)

Comment: :) "&nbsp;" is decoded to char 32 by the browser. JSTL will treat &nbsp; as the literal characters "&nbsp;", not the character represented by char code 32. Scriptlets, as I showed above, give you the flexibility to experiment with raw char codes. good luck.. bye :)